# Redirection after sweetalert closes

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to be redirected to another page after the sweetalert modal closed on timeout.
I am using the following code. Modal is showing and it is closing after timer ends but new page is  not being redirected.

```
$('#with-timer').on('click', function () {
    var timerInterval;
    swal({
      title: 'Auto close alert!',
      html: 'I will close in <strong>2</strong> seconds.',
      timer: 2000
    }).then(function (result) {
      if (result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer) {
        window.location.href = "index.php";
      }
    });
  });
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: What SweetAlert are you using? SweetAlert, SweetAlert for Bootstrap or SweetAlert2. Exact version?

Comment: I got your code working with SweetAlert2 but had to change `swal({...` into `swal.fire({...`. Maybe you're using the dissmiss-reason feature of SweetAlert2 with another SweetAlert variant that doesnt support this?

Comment: Try to use document.location = "index.php";

Comment: How is this php related?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `replace()` instead of `href()`

**Change your code to**

```
.then(function (result) {
      if (result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer) {
        window.location.replace = "index.php";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing sweetalert with sweetalert2. They have different APIs. It looks like sweetalert2 tells you the reason why an alert is dismissed, so I'll use it for this answer, though it uses `swal.fire` to open up an alert.

Here's a working example:

```js
$('#with-timer').on('click', function () {
    var timerInterval;
    swal.fire({
      title: 'Auto close alert!',
      html: 'I will close in <strong>2</strong> seconds.',
      timer: 2000
    }).then(function (result) {
      if (result.dismiss === swal.DismissReason.timer) {
        window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<button id="with-timer">Open Modal</button>
```